# Convert an array of character to string from index i to j in c++

Tags: c++, char, stdstring

I have an array of chars in c++.for example :

```
char input[]="I love you";
```

I want to make a std::string from char[i] to char[j]. for example :

```
std::string output="love";
```

What should i do?

Comment: Use the iterator pair constructor.

Comment: I don't mean that.
in my program I don't know the context of input array of characters!!!

Comment: You seem like you want an index-based range. You can form iterators using indices. I don't see the problem.

Comment: Have you even tried anything, like... oh, I don't know: treating the array as a pointer (pointer arithmetic and all that: `input + i, input + j` is what I'm getting at here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
char input[]="I love you";
std::string str(input);
```

here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/

if you want only part so write this:

```
std::string str(input + from, input + to);
```

Comment: He just wants some characters, not the entire array.

Answer (score 0):

`std::string` has a constructor that takes an iterator pair. You can substitute pointers for it..

Example:

```
#include <iostream>


int main() 
{
    char input[]="I love you";

    std::string str = std::string(&input[2], &input[6]);
    std::cout<<str;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example in which the following constructor

```
basic_string(const charT* s, size_type n, const Allocator& a = Allocator());
```

is called

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    char input[] = "I love you";
    std::string s( input + 2, 4 );

    std::cout << s << std::endl;
}
```

Or you can use constructor

```
basic_string(const basic_string& str, size_type pos, size_type n = npos,
             const Allocator& a = Allocator());
```

as in this example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    char input[] = "I love you";
    std::string s( input, 2, 4 );

    std::cout << s << std::endl;
}
```